# Unable to pass appropriate shape to tensor flow model with tf.data.Dataset.from_generator

Tags: python, tensorflow

When using tf.data.Dataset.from_generator API to generate train and test datasets. Not able to pass the appropriate shape to the Tensorflow model.

Following is my code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd


def fetchValuesFromDatabase(path):
  df = pd.read_csv(path, header=None)
  rows_from_csv = df.values[:]
  rows_list = rows_from_csv.tolist()
  rows_list = rows_list[1:]

def castFunction(val):
    try:
        return int(val)

    except:
        return int(float(val))

result_column = [list(map(lambda x: castFunction(x), value[-1])) for value in rows_list]
train_columns = [list(map(lambda x: castFunction(x), value[3:-1])) for value in rows_list]
print(train_columns)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_columns, result_column, test_size=0.20, shuffle=True)


train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train)).batch(32)
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, y_test)).batch(32)

return train_dataset, test_dataset


def createModel():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(10, input_shape=(10,), activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model


model = createModel()

train_dataset, test_dataset = fetchValuesFromDatabase("ModifiedHrTrainData.csv")

model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10, validation_data=test_dataset)
```

Getting following error.

ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 10 but received input with shape [10, 1]

The same error doesn't occur if tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices is used and passed to the model. Need help in achieving the same with tf.data.Dataset.from_generator API.

Following is the dataset link

https://mega.nz/file/DZkVWSTT#MhjiuFcDMbe80gZ34AkMCjWD3h3y87ytpn9q4AT1bu4

Please help me understand the issue.

Comment: @Sumanth what is the output of `print(train_columns)`?

Comment: @rnivas , it prints list of training column lists like  [ [1, 1, 0, 1, 37, 2, 6, 56, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 27, 5, 3, 79, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 29, 1, 2, 45, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 27, 1, 5, 49, 0, 0].........]

Answer (score 0):

Add keras_input function to your model `tf.keras.Input(shape=(10`,))`

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(10,)))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model
```